# How to decode URL with Persian slug in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, apache, url-routing, cpanel

I have an archive view that using Persian slug like:

> چینیها-خورشید-مصنوعی-هم-ساختند

with this url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    path('archive/<str:slug>/', views.ArchiveDetailView.as_view(),

    ...
]
```

models.py:

```
class Archive(models.Model):
    ...

    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)

    ...
```

views.py:

```
class ArchiveDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Archive

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, slug=slug)
```

This work fine in local with Django built-in web server. But when I deploy site on my host (cPanel) return 404 error (only for Persian slug).

I think I find the problem, but I don't know how to fix it?

Problem is when slug in Persian, web server (Apache) or Django can't decode URL.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Routine reports. @PedroLobito

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way for using Persian slug is to use regular expressions, it is better for decoding and it may solve your problem.

```
form django.urls import re_path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/', views.detail),
]
```

or if you want to add more item for url dispatching you can use below example.

```
re_path(r'detail/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/', views.detail)
```

For more detail click the following link:
https://www.mongard.ir/one_part/73/django-persian-urls/